# Как сделать кеш на Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Поставлена задача - реализовать кеширование для Wordpress плагина, на сайте wordpress. К сожалению, серверное кеширование не подойдет. Самая сложность, бизнес логика написана на JS (запросы идут оттуда).

Все, что пришло в голову - сделать свой роут wordpress, и стучать с JS на него, а далее делать запрос через PHP.

**Вопросы:**

- Видел библиотеку Phpfastcache. Но у нее нет адаптера под mysql. А просить администратора Wordpress установить Redis возможности нет. Есть аналоги под эту цель?
- Есть ли какие-то библиотеки для написания proxy. Или написать самому?
- Может есть идеи, как решить эту задачу лучше?

Comment: можно использовать возможности кеширования вебсервера nginx или кеширующего сервера varnish

Comment: @AlekseyVaganov, к сожалению, это серверный вариант.

Comment: а вам какой нужен?

Comment: @AlekseyVaganov мне необходимо в бд wordpress сделать таблицу с кешем... P.S понимаю, что звучит дико, но не моя идея((